# Does any one had tried to connect MK850 PERFORMANCE to ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

I always thought that all the bluetooth keyboards works seamlessly with ubuntu, but seems this is not the case with logitech keyboards.

I cannot find the device in the bluetooth settings,

> Any one who has successfully managed it do it , post the instructions
>   here :)

Moreover I can connect to iPad, android phone, windows and mac without any problems and in the [site](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/mk850-wireless-keyboard-mouse-combo#specification-tabular) they have mentioned that they also support chrome os but linux (WTF) is not mentioned any where :(

I have verified myself that it works with another laptop which has different version of ubuntu.

Comment: In terminal with the keyboard in pairing mode, enter `bluetoothctl` then `scan on` does the keyboard appear as a new device in terminal?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I cannot see any my keyboard and mouse in the devices list :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that it has been some time, but I would like to add that I just purchased an MK850 Keyboard and Mouse combo specifically for the Bluetooth connectivity. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 Minimal Install on a Lenovo Flex 5. The keyboard and mouse connected without issue via Bluetooth. No need for the USB dongle. In fact, I didn't even take the USB dongle out of the box. I would say that it was kind of slow hooking up. The whole process took maybe 3 to 4 minutes however, I'm very impatient. May have been 2 minutes...

I did NOT install Solaar. Maybe this would have helped but I'm up and running so I don't see the need for it myself.

Comment: I have two questions: 1. When you you say "the whole process took 3 to 4 minutes", are you referring to the initial device pairing or is this a delay that happens every time you boot your computer? 2. Does the keyboard work before you Linux boots? For example, can you use the keyboard to get into bios setup? My Ubuntu laptop has an encrypted drive that I need to unlock before Linux starts. Thank you.

Comment: The 3 to 4 minutes was in reference to the initial pairing.

Comment: I do find myself hitting the space key to wake the keyboard at startup. I am running in EFI Fast Boot mode and rarely enter BIOS. I did enter BIOS on my laptop and basically, Bluetooth is not available on my computer at that point however I'm not sure that is your concern...

Comment: I can confirm that the MK850 keyboard and mouse works just fine with Ubuntu 18.04. When I first tried, only the mouse paired painlessly. The keyboard connected but did not pair. Today I forced Ubuntu to forget the keyboard (using the Bluetooth Manager's "Remove" operation.) When I tried to pair the keyboard after this, I was prompted with a 6-digit pairing code to enter on the keyboard. For some reason, I didn't notice this important step the first time - perhaps because I have installed KDE/Plasma on top and have both KDE & Gnome bluetooth configuration tools available. Bottom line: it works.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, I am having a hard time using the keyboard. It shown connected in the Bluetooth setting window but does not work(typing). Mouse work seemlessly

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to fix myself using the bluetooth dongle, which was given with MK850 keyboard + mouse (logitech unifying receiver) and using the software called

**[solaar](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/logitech-unifying-receiver-linux-solaar)**

- Install the software with the command mentioned below or follow the the instruction from the above link.

> apt-get install solaar

Note: Turn off/on the device, if you cannot pair right away.

*Not sure why the built in bluetooth does not work and I guess it is related to the issue mentioned [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338474)*

Comment: If a blue-tooth device is sold with its own receiver, it almost never works with other blue-tooth receivers. I call it hard-paired.

Comment: I kind of agree, but my phone mac ipad works with built in bluetooth  :)

Comment: @user680858, this is a multi-device setup which can connect to the Logitech Unifying Receiver (the dongle) *and* one more more bluetooth devices. The Logitech Unifying Receiver doesn't even use Bluetooth - at least not in a standards-compliant manner.

Answer (score 0):

I paired both the keyboard and mouse successfully on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Dell XPS 15: I simply launched the Bluetooth options from the settings app, and then on each device initiated pairing requests.

Each device appeared twice in the list of Bluetooth devices, so I had to try each in turn. It paid to turn off bluetooth between each test.
When you have the correct entry for the Keyboard, a 6 digit pairing code appears. Use the numbers across the top of the keyboard, not the number pad, as you cannot guarantee that the correct mode is enabled for the number pad (could be that num lock is on or off).

No special tricks or magic. Just read the Logitech instruction for new pairing: Press and hold the channel button on the device. In my case, I used channel 3 on both the KB and Mouse as I have assigned other devices already.

Comment: Hey @Manky, for me the keyboard shown connected but it is not typing. And it did not ask me passcode, just paired by itself. Any suggestion to make the keyboard work? The mouse is working fine.